# Make [ue5] a synonym for [unreal-engine5]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [ue5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ue5) has 61 questions, all related to the Unreal Engine in version 5. The tag [unreal-engine5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine5) has 332 questions and a tag description (where the [ue5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ue5) tag does not). The [ue5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ue5) tag should be a synonym for the more detailed tag [unreal-engine5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unreal-engine5).